# Assigning variables from variable values in a data frame to another data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, variable-assignment

I have 10 topics. For each topic name I have a `results_topic_df` data frame. In this data frame there are 2 columns: `index`, which is a name of another data frame and `var_name`, which is a name of a variable inside the corresponding data frame (indicated by `index`).

What I want to do is to take the corresponding original data frame (whos name is indicated by `results_topic_df$index`), look at the value of `results_topic_df$var_name` in the same row, go to the original data frame and copy the relevant variable to a data frame named `container_df`.

Eventually I will have `container_df` having only the selected variables from all the data frames that appear in `results_topic_df`.
I want to repeat this procedure **for each one of the 10 topics**.

I have tried to do this with a loop but because my data frames' names change, I got really confused with all the combinations of `assign()`,`paste0()`, and `eval()`. Is there a simpler way to accomplish my goal? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example

Comment: I don't have an easy example at the back of my sleeve. If you'll tell me what is it that you don't understand about my question I will try my best to explain again.